# decide $\sigma^{2020}$

Tags: permutations, permutation-cycles

I don't know how to do this. Please help me. [image]

Comment: sigma with permutations

Comment: find the order of permutation after that it will be more easy

Comment: break the permutation in disjoint set  $(1\; 3\; 4\;)(5\; 7\; 2\;)(8\; 6\; 10\;)(9)$ now the lcm of order of  these disjoint permutations will give you the order ,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply the permutation three times to any integer between 1 and 10 and observe you obtain the same integer back; i.e. $\sigma^3$ is the identity permutation. This means we can perform $\sigma^3$ an arbitrary number of times and it has no overall effect.

Since $2020=673\cdot 3+1$, we observe that we can write ${\sigma_3}^{2020}$ as ${\sigma_3}\circ ({\sigma_3}^3)^{673}$. What this is saying is that we effectively 'do nothing' 673 times, represented by the $({\sigma_3}^3)^{673}$, then apply once more the original permutation, to make a total of 2020 applications of the permutation.

So in fact ${\sigma_3}^{2020}={\sigma_3}\circ ({\sigma_3}^3)^{673}={\sigma_3}$.

I hope this helps.

Comment: no, not really, this task is the first task about permutations and i don't know how to deduce the answer. how do i have to calculate (σ3^3)^673∘σ3 ?

Comment: I've edited my answer. Let me know what is unclear still :)

Comment: thank u so much! it helps me a lot

Comment: You're welcome :)